# Error : the remote certificate is invalid according to validation procedure

Tags: c#, email, smtp

im trying to make a simple app to send emails, using our local email server.
I always get this error no matter how i debug it.
Can anyone help? i've been stuck in this for days.
Thanks

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXWET.png)

```
private void btnSendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("no-reply@mydomain.com.ph");
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(tbRecepient.Text.Trim());

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to)
            {
                Subject = tbSubject.Text.Trim(),
                Body = rtbBody.Text.Trim()
            };

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("172.11.3.25", 25)
            {
                EnableSsl = true,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("example@mydomain.com.ph", "password@2020")
            };

            try
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Given your mail server is using port 25, I would expect the `EnableSsl = true` line to be wrong.

Comment: i tried setting it to false,
response is "Authentication required"

Comment: Did you check the mail server webpage to see the required SMTP parameters?  Port 25 is the non secure email port number.  Secure email requires port number 465 or 587 depending on the server.  Network Credentials may not be accepted and you would need to setup a Pop Email account on your machine using Control Panel.